Where can the logs reported by FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log() and logEvent(...) be seen in the console?

As shown in the figure, where can the logs reported by calling FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log() and FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).logEvent(..., ...) be seen in the console?
I can only see the automatically collected crash logs.
Do I need to make other configurations in the code or console?
I expect to be able to see custom logs in the Firebase console.
